# How to empty a binding Combobox VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, combobox, visual-studio-2015

see this part of the code :
ds : dataset.
dt : table.

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

How do I do to empty this combobox ? because when I use the code below, I recieve an error message:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = Nothing
ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
```

can you help please ? thanks in advance

Comment: pls add error message you recieved also...

Comment: Why do you have cmbComboBox and ComboBox1 ? I think ComboBox1.Items.Clear() will be ok

Comment: Thanks Nbadaud for your answer , acorrect it. it's combobox1. I didn't copy the whole code. I gave you just a shortcut to now where the probleme occure

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ComboBox1.ResetText()
```